# Como implementar um método abstrato em uma classe filha?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Eu abstraí um método de uma classe também abstrata.

Mas não estou sabendo como implementar este método na classe filha.

Tá aqui o meu código, o que eu arrumo?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Banco_Exercicio1
{
    public class Cliente
    {


        public string Nome { get ; set ;}
        public string Rg { get ; set ;}
        public string Cpf {get ; set ;}

        public Cliente(string nome)
        {            
            this.Nome = nome;
        }
    }

    public abstract class Conta
    {
        public Cliente Titular { get; set; }
        public double Saldo { get; set; }
        public int Numero { get; set; }

        public Conta(Cliente nome)
        {
            this.Titular = nome;
        }

        public Conta() {}

        public abstract void Depositar(double Valor) ;


        public abstract void Saca(double Valor);   

    }

    public class ContaPoupanca : Conta // Essa linha apresenta erro: does not implement inherited abstract member
    {
        public ContaPoupanca(Cliente nome) : base(nome) { }

        public ContaPoupanca() {}

        public override void Saca(double Valor)
        {
            base.Saca(Valor + 0.10);     //Error: Cannot Call an abstract member
        }      
    }

    public class ContaCorrente : Conta
    {
        public ContaCorrente(Cliente nome) : base(nome) { }

        public ContaCorrente() {}

        public override void Saca(double Valor)
        {
            base.Saca(Valor + 0.05);    //Error: Cannot Call an abstract member
        }

        public override void Depositar(double Valor)
        {
            base.Depositar(Valor - 0.10);   //Error: Cannot Call an abstract member
        }
    }

    public class TotalizadordeContas 
    {
        public double ValorTotal {get ; private set ;}

        public double Soma (Conta conta)
        {
            ValorTotal += conta.Saldo;
            return ValorTotal; 
        }
    }

}
```

Como resolver e consertar estes erros?

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/054bda3b-40a6-4723-82ba-7c119ffdccd3/como-implementar-um-mtodo-abstrato-em-uma-classe-filha?forum=cermicrosoftpt#054bda3b-40a6-4723-82ba-7c119ffdccd3

Comment: Especifique a questão no conteúdo do post e não em um link.

Comment: Respondi também no Technet.

Answer (score 4):

O método da classe de base não pode ser chamado, pois ele não possui implementação na classe de base.

A chamada ao método da classe de base deve ser feito quando o método é virtual na classe de base, e não quando o método é abstrato.

**Analisando o seu código:** Pelo que eu entendi do seu código, a classe de base deveria possuir alguma responsabilidade, portanto, o método deve ser implementado na classe de base também, como um método virtual ao invés de abstrato:

Suponhamos que a classe de base tenha a responsabilidade de gravar no banco de dados. Neste caso você poderia fazer assim:

```
public abstract class Conta
{

    public Cliente Titular { get; set; }
    public double Saldo { get; set; }
    public int Numero { get; set; }

    public Conta(Cliente nome)
    {
        this.Titular = nome;
    }

    public Conta() {}
    public virtual void Depositar(double Valor)
    {
        // exemplo: gravar o valor depositado no banco de dados
        // usando o seu ORM
    }


    public virtual void Saca(double Valor)
    {
        // exemplo: gravar o valor sacado no banco de dados
        // usando o seu ORM
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Does not implement inherited abstract member

Implemente `Depositar` em `ContaPoupanca`:

```
public override void Depositar(double Valor) { ... }
```

## Cannot call an abstract member

A mensagem já diz tudo. Como na classe base o método é abstrato, não tem o que ser chamado. Logo, você não pode utilizar `base`.

Como o @MiguelAngelo disse, se o objetivo é que o método base seja chamado, use `virtual`.