# O que é e para que serve uma classe abstrata?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, classes-abstratas

Em orientação a objetos, qual é o significado de uma classe abstrata? Qual é a sua finalidade?

Comment: Alguma linguagem em específico? Acho que existem pequenas diferenças de uma linguagem pra outra.

Comment: De preferência em Java. Mas para classes abstratas, quando se trata de C#, há alguma diferença perceptível?

Comment: Relacionado: ["Classe Abstrata X Interface"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3603/classe-abstrata-x-interface?rq=1)

Comment: A pergunta citada pelo @mgibsonbr já serve pra responder a essa pergunta.

Comment: @Duds, eu tinha equivocadamente dado -1. Editei a sua pergunta para remover o voto negativo, ok? Quando der o OK, removo o comentário. +1

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Classes abstratas são classes que, basicamente, são apenas um **tipo** *abstrato* (com o perdão do trocadilho) de como as classes que a herdarem devem se comportar.

Classes abstratas não podem ser instanciadas, como já dito, elas servem apenas para que outras classes usem-na como **modelo** (herdem os atributos/propriedades e métodos delas).

Elas podem ter métodos abstratos ou não abstratos.
Os métodos abstratos **não podem ter corpo**, ou seja, deve-se declarar apenas a assinatura do método e eles **obrigatoriamente** terão que ser implementados na classe filha (a classe que herda), já os métodos que não forem assinados como `abstract` devem ter corpo e **podem ou não** ser sobrescritos na classe filha.

Um exemplo bem simples de uso de uma classe abstrata seria (exemplo em Java)

```java
abstract class Animal{        
    abstract String getHabitat();

    public String getRaca(){
        return "Raça indefinida";
    }
}

class Cachorro extends Animal{
    public String getHabitat(){
        return "";
    }
}

class Gato extends Animal{
    public String getHabitat(){
        return "indefinido";
    }

    public String getRaca(){
        return "Munchkin";
    }
}
```

Neste caso, qualquer classe que herdar de `Animal` deverá implementar o método `getHabitat()`, caso contrário ocorrerá um erro de compilação. Quanto ao método `getRaca()`, as classes filhas podem simplesmente usar o código que já existe na classe abstrata, sem se preocupar em implementá-lo.

Portanto, se fizeres

```java
Cachorro c = new Cachorro();
System.out.println(c.getRaca()); //A saída será "Raça indefinida"

Gato g = new Gato();
System.out.println(g.getRaca()); //A saída será "Munchkin"
```

Comment: sempre que há uma herança irá obrigatoriamente ter que haver uma classe abstracta? Qual pode ser um exemplo de uma utilidade "útil" de uma classe abstracta? (refiro-me C++, caso haja diferença para java)

Comment: Não precisa. Pelo menos em Java e C# não. Exemplo de classe útil vai da necessidade do programador... Não consigo pensar em nada agora.

Answer (score 22):

A função de uma classe abstrata é implementar *parcialmente* um tipo. O melhor exemplo que eu conheço é a classe [`AbstractList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) do Java: enquanto a interface [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) define um tipo, útil porém complexo, ela não provê uma implementação concreta haja vista que existem várias maneiras de se implementar uma lista, cada uma com seus prós e contras. O `ArrayList` e o `LinkedList` são duas delas. Mas nada impede que o programador crie suas próprias listas, se necessário.

Entretanto, muito do que o programador teria de implementar é igual para toda lista: se você implementa um método para acrescentar um elemento numa determinada posição, depois você tem que implementar outro para acrescentar no final, outro para acrescentar vários, outro para acrescentar vários numa posição específica, etc. É muito código para escrever... E se na interface você não possui nenhuma implementação concreta (interfaces servem apenas para **definir** um tipo), a classe abstrata permite que *parte do* código venha pronto pra você (se você não quiser/puder usar, é só sobrescrever), e a outra parte - principal - você escreve você mesmo.

Um exemplo simplificado:

```java
// Define um tipo
interface List {
    int size();
    Object get(int indice);
    boolean isEmpty();
    int indexOf(Object o);        
    Iterator iterator();
}

// Implementa parcialmente um tipo
abstract class AbstractList {
    // Esses são os métodos principais, então você é que tem que escrever
    abstract int size();
    abstract Object get(int indice);

    // Esses outros te dão uma "ajuda", fazendo uso do método que você escreveu
    boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    int indexOf(Object o) {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < size() ; i++ )
            if ( get(i).equals(o) )
                return i;
    }

    Iterator iterator() {
        return new Iterator() {
            int indice = 0;

            boolean hasNext() {
                return indice < size();
            }

            Object next() {
                 return get(indice++);
            }
        };
    }
}

// Implementa um tipo concreto
class ArrayList extends AbstractList {
    Object[] array;

    int size() {
        return array.length;
    }

    Object get(int indice) {
        return array[indice];
    }
}

// Outra implementação
class ListaCom3 extends AbstractList {
    Object obj1;
    Object obj2;
    Object obj3;

    int size() { return 3; }
    Object get(int indice) {
        if ( indice == 0 ) return obj1;
        if ( indice == 1 ) return obj2;
        if ( indice == 2 ) return obj3;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Repare que a interface (tipo) exige 5 métodos, mas com a ajuda da classe abstrata cada implementação "final" só precisa implementar 2.

Comment: Muito bom exemplo @mgibsonbr! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 20):

Todas respostas estão certas. Só quero adicionar uma informação simples do que é a classe abstrata.

Ela é um meio termo entre a classe concreta e a interface.

Ela não deixa de ter alguma implementação, ou seja, tem estado (variáveis) e comportamento (métodos), inclusive membros privados, como qualquer outra classe, mas também possuem métodos públicos sem implementação, ou seja apenas como contratos, exatamente como o ocorre com interfaces.

Assim como ocorre com interfaces, estes métodos, chamados de abstratos, deverão ser implementados na classe concreta que deriva desta abstrata.

Dependendo da situação uma classe abstrata pode ser usada como se fosse uma interface, já que a interface é uma classe puramente abstrata (não tema nada que não seja abstrato).

Algumas linguagens estão adotando algumas características de classe abstrata em interfaces, mas não tudo obviamente.

Para entender melhor, sugiro algumas leituras:

- [Classe Abstrata X interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/101)
- [Quando devo usar Herança, Classe Abstrata, Interface ou um Trait?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73449/101)
- [Interface ou Abstract?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35317/101)
- [Por que todo mundo odeia herança múltipla em C++ e qual sua diferença para mixins?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42970/101)
- [Construtor classe abstract](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31951/101)
- [Como implementar um método abstrato em uma classe filha?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12430/101)
- [Implementar Interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47925/101)
- [Por que os métodos implementados de uma interface não podem ser privados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58891/101)
- [Interface vs Class - visibilidade de métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63869/101)
- [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por que?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vou favoritar, só pra futuramente ler estes conteúdos.

Comment: Muito obrigado @bigown!

Answer (score 9):

As classes abstratas servem como “modelo” para outras classes que dela herdem, não podendo ser instanciada por si só. Para ter um objeto de uma classe abstrata é necessário criar uma classe mais especializada herdando dela e então instanciar essa nova classe. Os métodos da classe abstrata devem então serem sobrescritos nas classes filhas.

```java
abstract class Conta { 
    private double saldo; 

    public void setSaldo(double saldo) { 
        this.saldo = saldo; 
    } 

    public double getSaldo() { 
        return saldo; 
    } 

    public abstract void imprimeExtrato(); 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Para melhor entendimento, uma classe abstrata serve como um "modelo" de herança para uma classe concreta.

Como uma classe abstrata não pode ser instanciada por si só, é necessário, conforme dito antes, criar uma classe concreta extender da classe abstrata. Desse modo, os métodos oriundos da classe abstrata devem ser sobrescritos nas classes "filhas". Porém, se uma classe abstrata herdar de outra classe abstrata, não é necessária a implementação dos métodos abstratos.

Exemplo:

Classe abstrata:

```java
abstract class Funcionario {

  protected double salario;

  public double getBonificacao() {
    return this.salario * 1.2;
}
```

Classe concreta:

```java
class Gerente extends Funcionario {

  public double getBonificacao() {
    return this.salario * 1.4 + 1000;
  }
}
```

Referêcias: http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/classes-abstratas/#9-3-metodos-abstratos

Comment: Uma dúvida, quando uma classe abstrata não possui método abstrato, não é obrigatório sobrescrever esse método? Somente será obrigatória a sobrescrita de método quando o método for abstrato?

Comment: Exatamente @Duds

Comment: Seria legar dar os devidos créditos à [Caelum](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/classes-abstratas/#9-2-classe-abstrata)

Answer (score 2):

Uma Classes abstratas são classes que, definem a estrutura mais elementar de uma classe que você possa criar. Elas não podem ser instanciadas, mas servem de base para criar outras a partir dela. As classes que herdarem a abstrata em questão, terão suas características, como método e atributos.

Os métodos abstratos não podem ter codificação, mas temos que declara-los e, obrigatoriamente, implementa-los. Os métodos impementados, devem ter código e podem ser ou não sobrescritos pela classe herdeira.