# O que é uma classe de tipo "class MinhaClasseExemplo<T> where T: new(){}"?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, classes, genéricos

Uma classe `class ExemploClass<T>` é uma lista? Veja a classe exemplo abaixo:

```
public abstract class MinhaClasseExemplo<T> where T: new()
{
   public T value {get; set;}
}
```

O que siginifica cada parte desta expressão: `abstract class MinhaClasseExemplo<T>`, `where`, `T`, `:` e `new()`  e qual é a finalidade de uma classe deste tipo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provavelmente não é uma lista, é uma estrutura de dados qualquer, poderia ser se tivesse outras partes que indicasse isso.

O `abstract` significa que a [classe é abstrata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101). Ela não pode ser instanciada, ela só pode ser usada como mãe de outra classe em herança.

`<T>` é usado para indicar o que será o tipo genérico. É uma espécie de super variável que será substituída por um tipo real quando a classe for instanciada. É usado para obter [genericidade de tipos em classes e métodos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Assim a classe pode trabalhar com vários tipos diferentes de forma segura do ponto de vista de tipos, que é ótimo em linguagens que prezam por tipos estáticos.

Então nesse exemplo, se a instância for `MinhaClasseExemplo<string>`, a propriedade na instância ficaria assim: `public string value {get; set;}`. É uma forma de usar a mesma classe para vários tipos sem ter que escrever uma versão para cada tipo.

O `where T: new()` é uma [restrição](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) do que o `T` pode ser, no caso ele só aceitará [tipos que tenham um construtor padrão](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Nesse caso específico é uma convenção dizer que `new()` é essa exigência. Alguns problemas poderiam ocorrer se não tiver uma restrição. Afinal a operação que será executada dentro da classe com esse tipo pode exigir um determinado recurso. Sem a restrição poderia ser usado um tipo que não tem o recurso esperado e não funcionaria. Obviamente o compilador já pega esse erro e nem deixa usar um tipo qualquer. Quando você restringe quais tipos podem ser usados, fica garantido que eles podem ser usados. Na página da documentação pode ser visto outras formas de restrição que podem ser usadas.

Nesse exemplo específico a única coisa que posso dizer sobre a classe é que ela será usada como base para outra classe e que partes dela pode ter o seu tipo definido de acordo com a instanciação. Qualquer outra informação seria especulação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).