# Como declarar um atributo em interface?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Como posso declarar alguns atributos em uma interface? Exemplo, tenho a interface chamada `animal`, quero que ela tenha alguns atributos que a classe `mamifero` vai implementar, mas o atributo que eu declaro na interface não dá certo.

```
interface Animal {
   protected $peso, $altura; 
}
```

O código acima gera erro de sintaxe no NetBeans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que você deseja na verdade é uma [classe abstrata](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) e não uma interface. Se realmente precisar. Inclusive pelo nome, um animal não deveria ser uma interface já que este mecanismo é para indicar capacidades e não objetos.

[Herança não é algo para usar em qualquer coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101), tem certos critérios. E um membro protegido também é raro ser útil quando feito certo. Na maioria das vezes que se usa isto não deveria. geralmente esta hierarquia específica do exemplo serve para mostrar como funciona herança, mas é péssimo para ensinar orientação a objetos de verdade. Em biologia é muito complicado fazer hierarquias corretamente, as coisas não são tão lineares quanto parece e a modelagem costuma não funcionar.

Entenda mais sobre [classes abstratas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101) (aí tem *links* para outras coisas, inclusive explicando a diferença para a interface.

[Não gosto do termo atributo, prefiro campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, então o correto neste caso não é usar a interface e sim uma classe.

Comment: É, uma classe abstrata.

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, o que você procura é uma **Classe Abstrata**, não uma Interface.
Acho importante fazer uma breve distinção entre Interfaces e Classes Abstratas, já que você parece ter certa dúvida na diferença entre o funcionamento de ambas. Lembrando, ambos são conceitos da Programação Orientada a Objeto.

**Irei exemplificar utilizando a linguagem Java, mas o funcionamento é similar em PHP:**

---

**Interfaces**

---

Funcionam como contratos firmados entre você e sua classe, onde você apresenta certas garantias do funcionamento da classe; todas as classes que **implementam** uma certa interface devem implementar todos os métodos (funções) declarados na interface, ou o código não irá compilar. Como os métodos são implementados, entretanto, não é importante, podendo até haver um corpo vazio de método.

A apostila da Caelum sobre Orientação a Objeto traz [um exemplo](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/interfaces/#10-6-exercicios-avancados-opcionais) simples sobre esse tipo de interação que ajuda a entender o conceito; no exemplo, uma interface chamada Conta é criada, e quatro métodos são declarados (cada um com seu retorno específico)

```
public interface Conta {
  public double getSaldo();
  public void deposita(double valor);
  public void saca(double valor);
  public void atualiza(double taxaSelic);
}
```

Após, podemos criar uma classe ContaCorrente que irá implementar a interface Conta, garantindo assim que ela possuirá todos os métodos básicos de uma Conta, independente de sua especialidade.

```
class ContaCorrente implements Conta {

  // outros atributos e métodos

  public double getSaldo() {...}
  public void deposita(double valor) {...}
  public void saca(double valor) {...}
  public void atualiza(double taxaSelic) {...}
}


class ContaPoupanca implements Conta {

  // outros atributos e métodos

  public double getSaldo() {...}
  public void deposita(double valor) {...}
  public void saca(double valor) {...}
  public void atualiza(double taxaSelic) {...}
}
```

O interessante de Interfaces é que você pode criar contratos com múltiplas interfaces, indicando assim que sua classe deverá realizar funcionalidades atreladas a conceitos distintos. Por exemplo, um classe Cachorro pode implementar as interfaces Animal, Bipede e Mamifero. Isso é a forma que algumas linguagens de programação utilizam para implementar **Herança Múltipla**.

É importante citar, entretanto, que cada classe que implementar a interface deve declarar sua própria implementação dos métodos.

---

**Classes Abstratas**

---

Em resumo, funcionam como **blueprints**, quer dizer, **modelos** de funcionamento de uma classe. Classes Abstratas são um dos conceitos bases da **Herança**. Classes Abstratas **não podem** ser inicializadas por si só, devendo sempre haver uma classe concreta que herde da classe abstrata. Classes abstratas possibilitam a declaração de variáveis e métodos padrões para todas as classes que herdarem da mesma. Dessa forma, tomando o exemplo das contas bancárias citadas acima, poderia declarar dados padrões para todas as contas (variáveis) e implementações padrões dos métodos declarados:

*Nota: para facilitar o exemplo, estarei usando **double** para declarar valores, mas você não deve usar double ou float para valores que necessitam de grandes precisões porque cálculos subsequentes com a variável diminuem a precisão da mesma podem modificar seu valor ao longo do caminho, a não ser que utilize métodos para normalizar os valores e reduzir essa varição.*

```
public abstract class Conta {
  private double saldo;
  private String nome;
  private String sobrenome;
  private int idade;

  public double getSaldo() {return this.saldo;}
  public String getNome() {return this.nome;}
  public String getSobrenome() {return this.sobrenome;}
  public int getIdade() {return this.idade;}
  public void deposita(double valor) {this.saldo += valor;}
  public void saca(double valor) {
    if (saldo > valor) 
      saldo -= valor;
    else System.out.println("Não é possível sacar esse valor");
  }
  public void atualiza(double taxaSelic) {}
}
```

Se quando implementando uma **interface** a classe é obrigada a criar sua própria implementação dos métodos declarados, quando **herdando** de uma classe abstrata, os métodos declarados na classe abstrata já são prontamente utilizáveis pela classe que a herdou. A classe concreta assume um papel de filha, que pode utilizar tudo aquilo que foi declarado em seu pai.

*Imagine que seu pai tem um carro. O carro não é seu, mas você, como filho, pode utilizar o carro para sair ocasionalmente.*

```
public class ContaPoupanca extends Conta {

  public ContaPoupanca (double saldo, String nome, String sobrenome, int idade) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    this.idade = idade;
  }
  public void atualiza(double taxaSelic) {
    this.saldo *= 1 + taxaSelic;
  }
}
```

Diferente de Interfaces, uma classe pode herdar diretamente somente de uma outra classe. Não há como uma classe Cachorro herdar diretamente de Animal, Bipede e Mamífero, já que cada uma dessas classes podem possuir declarações de métodos com assinaturas idênticas, mas implementações diferentes, o que causaria conflitos durante a compilação do programa.

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite, amigo.

Isso foge um pouco dos conceitos de POO, pois uma interface tem que ser uma "classe puramente abstrata", no máximo conter assinaturas de métodos á serem implementados de acordo com a necessidade da classe que extendê-las.

Atualmente temos o conceito de "Default Methods", onde uma interface pode ter métodos concretos, ou seja, já em sua forma usual, em algumas linguagens os atributos podem até ser declarados, mas essa não é uma prática recomendável recomendável.

Comment: Dá uma lida de novo na pergunta.

Comment: Entendi agora eu não encontrava na internet nenhum exemplo de interface com atributos apenas métodos, obrigada pela resposta.

Comment: @Maniero, obrigado por complementar. Realmente me equivoquei e não aprofundei. Agora ficou claro que ele precisava de uma Classe abstrata...

Comment: Procura por default method em PHP

Comment: Putz, @Maniero.
Vi aqui que PHP não da suporte a Default Methods...
Obrigado pela informação.
Realmente foi falta de atenção minha, pois realmente não li direito a pergunta (respondi como se fosse única e exclusivamente sobre POO)!

Comment: Mesmo que fosse genericamente OOP *default method* basicamente só existe em Java. E algumas pessoas consideram até violação do OOP.